# Is Miner Extractable Value (MEV) possible on Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: bsc, mev

Is it possible to arbitrarily order transactions on Binance Smart Chain as is the case on Ethereum to allow for MEV?

I could not find anything on google about this topic.  I hope it's appropriate to ask here.

Thanks.

Comment: Miner Extractable Value is for the miner, not for you

Comment: For you, it is arbitrage , priority gas auction or running attacks against other bots

Comment: everybody does arbitrage on BSC , that's what it is for

Comment: but you will have to spend a lot of money and time if you want a piece of the pie

Comment: Maybe I should of removed the word MEV from the question.  All I am really interested in "Is it possible to arbitrarily order transactions on Binance Smart Chain as is the case on Ethereum?"

Comment: I may suggest adding the word "auction" (like Nulik said: priority gas auction) as that is what flashbots (on ethereum) do

Comment: It is a good question tho, since MEV is a way for the miner to make profits, but it could hurt the bottomline of the users. This happens on Ethereum, since it is permissionless and anyone can mine. But BSC is PoSA, so only authorised parties can validate. So they shouldn't do MEV, right? Since they are maximising their profits, but making the blockchain less efficient. But do they do it?

Comment: @curiousTrader good observation, we should be able to take a look at the code posted on [github](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc) and see if MEV is already incorporated in the codebase, but we also don't have the guarantee that validators are using that exact codebase (I'd say it is pretty likely they do use that code, but idk)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done, and in fact, has happened, although it is not generalized.

First, remember that mev has the word miner on its name for a reason, so in the case of BSC mev would be done by validators, and since they are only 21 of them, and is crazy expensive becoming one of them, is almost certain that you can't do mev in BSC.

What you can do is finding arbitration, liquidations, frontrunning and snipping opportunities, and since there is not a flashbot equivalent (at least not publicly), you have to do it the old fashioned way, via a gas auctuon on the mempool.

The end result is mostly the same (the miner, or in this case validator) gets the biggest cut of the pie) but since the auction takes place on the network (instead of flashbot relay service) the network gets more congested.

PS: there is nodereal's direct route service, but since only 3 of 21 validator take part in said service, is far from flasbots' 80% eth hashrate